# Testing: Mocha and node differ re fs.exists

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

First, while I'm an experienced programmer, I'm relatively new to node, and very new to mocha, so my issue may be ME!  In which case, I'll be happy to find that out too!

Some code I'm writing makes use of an npm module which contains a call to fs.exists.  I get different results when I run a test with fs.exists when run via node vs when run vs mocha; in my opinion, I should be receiving the same answer; the file does exists, so the result should be true in both cases, but instead, it's true when invoked via node, and false when invoked via mocha.  Well, it's not functioning correctly.

I'm aware that fs.exists is deprecated, but that's in the npm module I'm using, so unless I modify the module, that's what I'm using.

The difference is associated with how I invoke mocha.

Per some site recommendations, I edited my package.json file to include, in the 'scripts' section, the following statement: "test": "mocha test", and I have placed my tests in this 'test' directory.  This is invoked via npm test.

After experiencing problems, I also installed did npm install -g mocha.

My test file is testVersion.js

The result is that I get different answers when I invoke one of the following three ways when invoking fs.exists via node, npm test, and mocha testVersion.js; I'm expecting 'true':
 - node testVersion.js returns true - it finds the file.
 - mocha testVersion.js returns true - it finds the file.
 - npm test returns false - it does not find the file.

I'm suspecting that maybe different versions of mocha or node are being invoked on me, but don't have enough experience to be able to determine this on my own.

**So my question is: why am I getting different results?**

Here's my code for testVersion.js

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var assert = expect.assert;
var fs = require("fs");
var isInTest = typeof global.it === 'function';  //exe via mocha or node

console.log('isInTest mode: ', isInTest);

if(!isInTest) {
  console.log('NOT TEST MODE: invoking fs.exists');
  fs.exists("testVersion.js", function(info) {
    console.log('NOT TEST MODE: fs.exists callback RAN.');
    console.log('NOT TEST MODE: fs.exists: should be true and is: ', info);
  })
}



if(isInTest) {
  describe("Test Mocha and fs.exists issue", function() {
    it("Test that file self exists.", function() {
      console.log('TEST MODE: invoking fs.exists');
      expect(fs.exists("testVersion.js", function(result) {
        console.log('TEST MODE: fs.exists callback RAN.');
        console.log('TEST MODE: fs.exists: should be true, and is: ', result);
        return true;
      })).to.equal(true);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the version of mocha installed globally (i.e. what you got when you ran `npm install -g mocha`) is not the same as the version specified in package.json, which maybe is what npm test uses?

Comment: Can you add your package.json (at least the devDependencies bit)?

Comment: ' "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^3.5.0",
        "mocha": "^2.4.5",
        "mocha-sinon": "^1.1.5",
        "sinon": "^1.17.3"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha test"
      },'

Comment: Wanted to say 'thanks' Mark!

Comment: I also went to the global mocha (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha) package.json, and it says "version": "2.4.5"

Comment: Ok, 2.4.5 seems to be the latest so both of those should resolve to the same version of mocha. npm & node are packaged together so will be the same version... Strange!

Comment: Maybe it is something to do with the base file path being different when run with npm test? Try it with an absolute path?

Comment: (As in, try it with setting an absolute path for the call to fs.exists)

Comment: Mark, I've tried setting it to various paths: ./testVersion.js as well as the full path beginning with /home.  Same results - fs.exists returned true for all except npm test.  I also ran two node versions on it, which are both different versions on my system: node testVersion.js and nodejs testVersion.js.  nodejs is version v0.10.25 and node is version v5.8.0.  Both gave the correct answer of 'true' meaning the file was located.  So, still the only one that is failing is the npm test, which returns false for fs.exists, which is incorrect.

Comment: I originally went down this rabbit hole because my small database nedb was doing exactly the same thing, and I was simplifying the problem down to the testVersions.js file.  npm test, with a test for nedb results was  not functioning correctly, whereas node and nodejs were functioning correctly.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of testing work, I believe my problem was because of async calls associated with fs.exists.  At any rate, the following is working for me, and I wanted to document it in case it helps anyone else.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.existsSync("bbq.js", function(result) {
  console.log('False: fs.exists(bbq.js) says: ', result);
})

fs.existsSync("test2.js", function(result) {
  console.log('True: fs.exists(test2.js) says: ', result);
})

describe('Testing Synch fs.existsSync() ===', function() {
  describe('False: fs.exists(bbq.js)', function() {
    it("This assertion should pass, as we are asserting false on file that doesn't exist.", function() {
      assert.equal(false, fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/bbq.js", function(result) { return result;}))
    });
  });

  describe('Testing Synch fs.existsSync(test2.js method A)', function() {
    it("This assertions should pass as we are asserting true on file that does exist", function() {
      assert.equal(true, fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/test2.js", function(result) {
        return result;
      }));
    });
  });

  describe('Testing Synch fs.existsSync(test2.js method B)', function() {
    it("This assertions should pass as we are are asserting true on file that does exist using callback", function() {
      fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/test2.js", function(result) {
        assert.equal(true, result);
      });
    });
  });
});


////////////////////

describe('Asynch test of fs.exists() === some results are UNDEFINED because of async', function() {
  describe('False: fs.exists(bbq.js)', function() {
    it("This assertion should pass as we are expecting undefined result due to async.", function() {
      assert.equal(undefined, fs.exists(__dirname + "/bbq.js", function(result) { return result;}))
    });
  });

  describe('True: fs.exists(test2.js method A)', function() {
    it("This assertion should pass as we are expecting undefined result due to async.", function() {
      assert.equal(undefined, fs.exists(__dirname + "/test2.js", function(result) {
        return result;
      }));
    });
  });


  describe('True: fs.exists(test2.js method B)', function() {
    it("This equal assertion passes, because of use of callback waits for response.", function() {
      fs.exists(__dirname + "/test2.js", function(result) {
        assert.equal(true, result);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I was reading your question again a couple of days ago and realised you'd got problems with your async handling (while I was in the pub!), but forgot to come back and add an answer then, sorry about that! Glad you've got it sorted though. If you want to test async processes, that can be done - shout if you need a hand with that and I'll add an answer demonstrating how that's best done!